# Adding custom style to button added in QTableview

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have created one table by using `QTableview` and `QAbstractTableModel`. In the last column, I am also able to add a button for every row (right corner of that cell). Now I want to customize its style, like change the background color to black, border, etc.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: How did you add buttons?

Answer (score 0):

delegate.h:

```
class MyDelegate : public QItemDelegate {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    bool editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index); };
```

delegate.cpp:

```
 #include <QtGui>  #include "delegate.h"

 MyDelegate::MyDelegate(QObject *parent)
     : QItemDelegate(parent)  {  }


 void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const  {
     QStyleOptionButton button;
     QRect r = option.rect;//getting the rect of the cell
     int x,y,w,h;
     x = r.left() + r.width() - 30;//the X coordinate
     y = r.top();//the Y coordinate
     w = 30;//button width
     h = 30;//button height
     button.rect = QRect(x,y,w,h);
     button.text = "=^.^=";
     button.state = QStyle::State_Enabled;

     QApplication::style()->drawControl( QStyle::CE_PushButton, &button, painter);  }

 bool MyDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel
*model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)  {
     if( event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease )
     {
         QMouseEvent * e = (QMouseEvent *)event;
         int clickX = e->x();
         int clickY = e->y();

         QRect r = option.rect;//getting the rect of the cell
         int x,y,w,h;
         x = r.left() + r.width() - 30;//the X coordinate
         y = r.top();//the Y coordinate
         w = 30;//button width
         h = 30;//button height

         if( clickX > x && clickX < x + w )
             if( clickY > y && clickY < y + h )
             {
                 QDialog * d = new QDialog();
                 d->setGeometry(0,0,100,100);
                 d->show();
             }
     }  }
```

main.cpp

```
#include "delegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStandardItemModel model(4, 2);
    QTableView tableView;
    tableView.setModel(&model);

    MyDelegate delegate;
    tableView.setItemDelegate(&delegate);

    tableView.horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
    tableView.show();
    return app.exec(); }
```

Comment: Hi tanmayb, you posted an answer which looks like a supplement for your question. In case it is, please edit your question and remove the "answer".

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best approach is to use a style sheet.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

```
qApp->setStylSheet("QTableview QPushButton {" // apply only on push buttons inside a table view
    "    background-color: red;"
    "    border-style: outset;"
    "    border-width: 2px;"
    "    border-color: beige;"
    "}");
```

Comment: Are you sure?

It might change all the tableviews style and not just the button.

Comment: See first link section `Selector Types` table row with `Descendant Selector`. So this should impact only buttons inside a table view. Didn't test it that, but it should work.

Comment: It would be best if you will simply try it. AFAIK style sheet some times can have unwanted side effects, it depends on style you are using (and this is usually platform depended).

Comment: I tried this way and it worked for me. Now with that button, I want to delete that particular row for which the corresponding button is clicked.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: QPushButton *button;

    for (int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); i++)
    {
        button = new QPushButton;
        button->setText("Delete");
 button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { color: #E5E5E5; }");
        ui->tableview->setIndexWidget(model->index(i,2, QModelIndex()), button);
        connect(button, SIGNAL (released()), this, SLOT (handleButton()));
    }

Comment: do not cascade questions, simply ask a new one.